# ggplot2_Error: geom_point requires the following missing aesthetics: y

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to run rWBclimate package in RStudio. I copied the below code from [ROpenSci](https://ropensci.org/usecases/rwbclimate_intro.html) and pasted in RStudio. But I get error saying 'Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type list. Defaulting to continuous
Error: geom_point requires the following missing aesthetics: y

```
gbr.dat.t <- get_ensemble_temp("GBR", "annualavg", 1900, 2100)

## Loading required package: rjson

### Subset to just the median percentile
gbr.dat.t <- subset(gbr.dat.t, gbr.dat.t$percentile == 50)
## Plot and note the past is the same for each scenario
     ggplot(gbr.dat.t,aes(x=fromYear,y=data,group=scenario,colour=scenario))    
+ geom_point() +
geom_path() +
theme_bw() +
xlab("Year") +
ylab("Annual Average Temperature in 20 year increments")
```

I also tried to use geom_point(stat="identity") in the following way but didn't work:

```
ggplot(gbr.dat.t,aes(x=fromYear,y=data,group=scenario,colour=scenario))    
+ geom_point(stat="identity") +
geom_path() +
theme_bw() +
xlab("Year") +
ylab("Annual Average Temperature in 20 year increments")
```

I still get the same message "Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type list. Defaulting to continuous
Error: geom_point requires the following missing aesthetics: y"

Also, the result from str(gbr.dat.t) is given below:

```
> str(gbr.dat.t)
'data.frame':   12 obs. of  6 variables:
$ scenario  : chr  "past" "past" "past" "past" ...
$ fromYear  : int  1920 1940 1960 1980 2020 2020 2040 2040 2060 2060 ...
$ toYear    : int  1939 1959 1979 1999 2039 2039 2059 2059 2079 2079 ...
$ data      :List of 12
..$ : num 9.01
..$ : num 9.16
..$ : num 9.05
..$ : num 9.36
..$ : num 10
..$ : num 9.47
..$ : num 9.92
..$ : num 10.7
..$ : num 10.3
..$ : num 11.4
..$ : num 12.1
..$ : num 10.4
$ percentile: int  50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 ...
$ locator   : chr  "GBR" "GBR" "GBR" "GBR" ...
```

Looking for your helpful answers.

Comment: Please add the output of `str(gbr.dat.t)` to your question.

Answer (score 7):

Hope this helps. All I did was convert the gbr.dat.t$data to a numeric vector

```
library('rWBclimate')
library("ggplot2")

gbr.dat.t <- get_ensemble_temp("GBR", "annualavg", 1900, 2100)

## Loading required package: rjson

### Subset to just the median percentile
gbr.dat.t <- subset(gbr.dat.t, gbr.dat.t$percentile == 50)

#This is the line you were missing
gbr.dat.t$data <- unlist(gbr.dat.t$data)

## Plot and note the past is the same for each scenario
ggplot(gbr.dat.t,aes(x=fromYear,y=data,group=scenario,colour=scenario)) + geom_point() +
  geom_path() +
  theme_bw() +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("Annual Average Temperature in 20 year increments")
```

Comment: Thanks. It just worked. But not sure why would we need to unlist this? This is the first time I faced anything like this in ggplot2 although I am a new comer.

Comment: It is because every value inside your $data is a list item. That confuses ggplot. Alternatively you can just unlist within ggplot `..y=unlist(data)..` this way you don't modify the original dataset